# How to extract data from multiple text files with headers?

Tags: matlab, data-extraction

This is in response to my previous question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31205188/extracting-data-from-multiple-text-files-with-headers).

I found code and tried to modify it according to the format of my file. But this program is not working either. I have pasted the code and the error below.

**CODE**

```
files = dir('*.n2o');
nume1(files) = 1301;
for k = 1:numel(files)
    fid = fopen('files(k)', 'rt');
    Data = textscan(fid, '%f %f %f %f %f', 'headerLines', 43, 'CollectOutput', true);
    fclose(fid);
    Data= cell2mat( Data);        
end
```

**ERROR**

> Error using subsindex
>   Function 'subsindex' is not defined for values of class 'struct'.
>
> Error in trial3 (line 2)
>   nume1(files) = 1301;

Kindly help me in interpreting this error.

Answer (score 0):

The reason line 2 returns an error is because you are trying to index with a structure. "files" is a structure, you can only index with integers.

try something like this:

```
files = dir('*.n20');

for k=1:length(files.name)
    fid = fopen('files.name(k)', 'rt');
    Data = textscan(fid, '%f %f %f %f %f', 'headerLines', 43,'CollectOutput', true);
    fclose(fid);
    Headers(k)= cell2mat(Data);        
end
```

Comment: Thankyou so much for your response.I tried the below mentioned comment and it worked.                                                                                                                                                                           clear all
files = dir('*.n2o');
nfiles = 1301;
myData = cell(1,nfiles);

for k = 1:nfiles
    fid = fopen(files(k).name, 'rt');
    N2OData(k,:,:)=textscan(fid, '%f %f %f %f %f', 'headerLines', 43,                                     'CollectOutput', true);
    fclose(fid);
    %N2OData= cell2mat( Data);        
end